# Practical example of mock and stubs in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

There is enough `questions` which are related to this topic, but none provide `practial` example citing the difference.

According to **Fowler's article mocks are not stubs**, stubs are fake methods independent from outside calls, while mocks are fake objects with pre-programmed reactions to calls.

**Stub's can't make your test fail, but Mocks can.**

> Mocking is more specific and object-related: if certain parameters are
>   passed, then the object returns certain results. The behavior of an
>   object is imitated or "mocked".
>
> Stubbing is more general and method-related: a stubbed method usually
>   returns always the same result for all parameters. The behavior of a
>   method is frozen, canned or "stubbed".

Let's take a simple `test` case. We have to find a `Book` provided with id and related to user.

```
  it "can find an Book that this user belongs to" do 
    project = Book.find( id: '22', email: user@test.com )      
    expect(project) to eq(some_data);  
  end
```

In the above case... What is stub and What is mock? If my example is not valid, can anyone show me `example` of Mock **and** stub.

Comment: Can you please link the mentioned article?

Comment: http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html

Comment: Yeah, so as I thought this article is about Java and naming conventions used are referring to some Java specific conventions and don't really have anything to do with Ruby & Rspec :)

Answer (score 1):

Lets get two examples:

```
let(:email) { 'email' }

# object created from scratch
let(:mocked_book) { instance_double Book, email: email } 
it 'check mock' do
  expect(mocked_book.email).to eq email
end

# 
let(:book) { Book.new }
it 'check stub' do
  allow(book).to receive(:email) { email }
  expect(book.email).to eq email
end
```

Your example is not that relevant: you wouldnt test active record, but you could need to `stub` it to return a `mock`

Say you need to test a book receives a method, something like:

```
def destroy
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  if @book.destroyable?
    @book.destroy
  else
    flash[:error] = "errr"
  end
  redirect_to books_path
end
```

You could test with this code:

```
it 'is not destroyed if not destroyable' do
  mocked_book = double 'book', destroyable?: false
  allow(Book).to receive(:find).and_return mocked_book
  expect(mocked_book).to_not receive :destroy
  # here goes the code to trigger the controller action
end

it 'is destroyed if destroyable' do
  mocked_book = double 'book', destroyable?: true
  allow(Book).to receive(:find).and_return mocked_book
  expect(mocked_book).to receive :destroy
  # here goes the code to trigger the controller action
end
```

You can see pros and cons here:

- cons: mocks must know exactly what are the expected methods
- pros: with mocks you dont need to really create an object and set it up to make it fit some conditions